# In iOS, how do I get the current CPU Utilization from inside an app that is running?

Tags: ios, profiling, instruments, activity-monitor

I'm looking for a way to get the CPU Utilization numbers like in Instruments and Activity Monitor with C/C++/Obj-C so I can do some automated testing with it. I'm looking for somewhere around a 1 second granularity, though 100 ms would be ideal. Another way to look at this question would be "How does Activity Monitor get the info it gets?".

Here's what I have found out so far:

- Many of the *nix equivalents don't seem to work with iOS

  - [sysctl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/sysctl.3.html)
    doesn't have KERN_CPTIME
  - iOS doesn't have the proc filesystem so I can't use
    /proc/stat.

    - This eliminates a lot of programs like vmstat and iostat
- MacOSX's 
  [sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sample.1.html)
  doesn't exist in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer. There is an undocumented API, host_processor_info() with the PROCESSOR_CPU_LOAD_INFO flavor, that can give you the number of system, user, nice, and idle ticks. You have to subtract the number of ticks from a previous call to it to get the current CPU utilization. Remember to call vm_deallocate on the array you get.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot.  The standard Un*x access to this information is not available within an iOS app.

Comment: I agree that the standard *nix ways of access aren't available, but how do Activity Monitor and Instruments get the info? It may be an undocumented or restricted API, but I'm hoping there's some public API that can do it.